# $http_origin in Nginx config files

Tags: nginx

I've seen it used in a lot of examples relating to CORS but where is the value of $http_origin set?

I checked the [Nginx variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) but there's no mention of it.
And there's no mention in [PHP FastCGI](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Comment: It is based on `headers` passed. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$http_<headername>` is automatically created based on the request headers. You can see the same on

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_

> **$http_name**
>
> arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

Answer (score 8):

If you look closer at http://nginx.org/docs/varindex.html, you'll notice there's only a single item with a prefix of `$http_` mentioned on that page; and, in fact, this single item is lacking any further suffix, being generic on purpose.

The functionality is documented over at http://nginx.org/r/$http_ as follows:

> `$http_name` — arbitrary request header field;
>   the last part of a variable name is the field name converted
>   to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

---

However, if you look into the source code behind nginx, it does have internal optimisations for storing certain specific request headers in individual variables for performance reasons (these are defined as a list in the code below, but they are henceforth placed into a hash table during the initialisation process of nginx by [`ngx_http_variables_add_core_vars()`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_variables_add_core_vars) function).  For example, `$http_host`, `$http_user_agent` and `$http_referer`, plus a bunch of other variables that may have to be handled internally by certain nginx components, or which may be frequently used within the configuration files.

- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#ngx_http_header_t
- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_core_variables
- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_variables_add_core_vars

However, as an end-user, you don't really have to worry about those kinds of details — the generic `$http_name` is sufficient to describe the whole functionality.  (In fact, `$http_origin` isn't special or popular enough to have warranted its own specialised handling.)